# Using .htaccess to block Googlebot from URLs ending with 4-6 digits, REGEX?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

How can we write .htaccess to block Googlebot UA from accessing URLs ending in forward-slash, followed by 4-6 digits?

We're wasting a lot of our Googlebot crawl budget because it's crawling "no-index" pages.

The plan is to use .htaccess to block the UA from URLs ending with a forward slash, followed by 4-6 digits.

Ex:

```
https://example.com/folder/folder/12563
https://example.com/folder/folder/125637
https://example.com/folder/folder/1563
```

I think the REGEX looks something like this:

```
\/\d{4,6}$
```

But how do I configure .htaccesss, and only for a specific UA (googlebot)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC]
RewriteRule /\d{4,6}$ - [F,L]
```

This will return a `Forbidden HTTP 403 error` for googlebot if they try to access the restricted URLs on your server.